# What's different between two dependencies sections in project.json

Tags: asp.net-core

Here is an example from a MVC project (I removed several items):

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        // (1)
        "Helios": "0.1-alpha-build-0585",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "0.1-alpha-build-1268"
    },
    "configurations": {
        "net45": {
            "dependencies": {
                // (2)
                "System.Data": "",
                "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": ""
            }
        },
        "k10": {
        }
    }
}
```

Can I move "System.Data" to (1) or move "Helios" to (2)?

What's different I put an assembly to (1) or (2)?

By the way, what does "" mean in the version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first dependencies node applies to all configurations. Meaning that is you add Helios to #1, it will be available both for net45 and k10.

The second section is configuration specific. If you add something to k10, it will not be available to net45 and vice versa.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/samples/MvcSample.Web/project.json) is an example of how that would look like when you have configuration specific packages.